# RPI Drive servo by PWM (wiringpi / C programming)

Tags: c, raspberry-pi3, pwm, servo, wiringpi

I trie to drive a servo with the Raspberry PI using the PWM on GPIO Pin 18 i wired the setup like you can see below.
[image]

When i drive the servo i can do this without any problems the commands that i use you can see below.

```
     gpio -g mode 18 pwm
     gpio pwm-ms
     gpio pwmc 192
     gpio pwmr 2000
     gpio -g pwm 18 150
     gpio -g pwm 18 200
```

That works fine, to go to the position without any problem but when i try to do the same with a C program using wiringpi like you can see below.

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
   printf ("Raspberry Pi wiringPi test program\n");
   wiringPiSetupGpio();
   pinMode (18, PWM_OUTPUT) ;
   pwmSetMode (PWM_MODE_MS);
   pwmSetRange (2000);
   pwmSetClock (192);
   pwmWrite(18,150);
   delay(1000);
   pwmWrite(18,200);
   return 0;
}
```

The program and the raspberry pi chrash so i have to reboot them does anybody know what i do wrong and how i can solve the problem it is very frustrating?

Comment: You probably want some manner of transient and ESD protection there. Toss in some TVS diodes with slightly higher voltage than the PWM, and some series resistors. But that's a topic for https://electronics.stackexchange.com. Oh and there's also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: oh yes i forget that i ga place it there to :p

Comment: Did you read manual for [wiringPiSetupGpio](http://wiringpi.com/reference/setup/)? _This is identical to above, however **it allows the calling programs to use the Broadcom GPIO pin numbers directly with no re-mapping.**_

_As above, this function needs to be called with root privileges, and note that some **pins are different from revision 1 to revision 2 boards.**_

Comment: But why it whorks when i use wiringpi in c to yust blink a LED with wiringpi i just have problems when using PWM

Comment: Even on the newest versions of wiringPi, the PWM functionality requires you to run your program with root privileges (ie. sudo). You are experiencing the crash/reboot issue because of this. To get around the sudo requirement, you'll need to use a digital potentiometer or digital-to-analog converter instead of the built-in PWM functionality.

Comment: I've not used wiringpi, so I don't know if this matters or not, but you're pwm line is connected to pin 18, not GPIO 18. GPIO 18 is at pin 12.

Comment: Additional note: Use GPIO18 & 19 (channel 0 & 1, ALT5, pins 12 & 35) or GPIO12 & 13 (channel 0 & 1, ALT0, pins 32 & 33) for **hardware_GPIO!**

Answer (score 0):

I spent weeks on controlling two servo (SG90) using WiringPi and programming in C, there're three things that I recommend.

1.Using `BCM GPIO` instead of `WiringPi Pin` because controlling more than one servo, you might need more than one pin such like 1(`WiringPi Pin`)/18(`BCM GPIO`) for another servo, For RPi3 B+ version, it give access to two channels for hardware PWM. Channel 0 on gpios 12/18 and channel 1 on gpios 13/19, it's easy and no need to worry about pin mapping exists if you adpopt `BCM GPIO`.

2.Better make sure there is only one program access PWM. pins at one time. Based on my experience, if you find that using command like "`gpio -g pwm 18 25`" is workable but otherwise using code like "`pwmWrite(18, 25)`" doesn's get any servo responds, maybe try "`ps -A`" to make sure if any other program is racing the access of your servo.

3.The last and the hardest one for me, when I execute `pwmWrite(18, 25)`" on `PWM. pin 18` triggers the same instruction onto `PWM. pin 12`, which means `pwmWrite(18, 25)` triggers `pwmWrite(12, 25)`. To solve this situation, changing the modes of other pins of servos which should freeze without any moving to be input mode and set all of them to be pull-down.

For details, codes for controlling two servos with PWM. Channel 0 on gpios 12/18.

**Basic function:**

```
void servo_init() {
    servo_open(0);
    delay(DELAY_SERVO);
    servo_open(1);}
```

and

```
void servo_open(int servo) {
switch (servo) {
    case 0:
        pullUpDnControl(SERVO_0, PUD_OFF);
        pinMode(SERVO_0, PWM_OUTPUT);
        pwmSetMode(PWM_MODE_MS);
        pwmSetClock(PWM_CHANNEL_0_CLOCK);
        pwmSetRange(PWM_CHANNEL_0_RANGE);
        break;
    case 1:
        pullUpDnControl(SERVO_1, PUD_OFF);
        pinMode(SERVO_1, PWM_OUTPUT);
        pwmSetMode(PWM_MODE_MS);
        pwmSetClock(PWM_CHANNEL_0_CLOCK);
        pwmSetRange(PWM_CHANNEL_0_RANGE);
        break;  
    default:

        break;
}}
```

and

```
void servo_close(int servo) {

switch (servo) {
    case 0:
        pinMode(SERVO_0, INPUT);
        pullUpDnControl(SERVO_0, PUD_DOWN);
        break;
    case 1:
        pinMode(SERVO_1, INPUT);
        pullUpDnControl(SERVO_1, PUD_DOWN);
        break;  
    default:

        break;
}}
```

and

```
void servo(int servo, int angle) {
switch (servo) {
    case 0:
        servo = SERVO_0;
        break;
    case 1:
        servo = SERVO_1;
        break;  
    default:
        servo = -1;
        break;
}
switch (angle) {
    case 90:
        value = 25;
        break;
    case -90:
        value = 10;
        break;
    case 0:
        value = 14;
        break;  
    default:
        break;
}
if (servo == -1) return;
pwmWrite(servo, value);}
```

**Rotate one servo connected to 18 (BCM GPIO)**

Close others before you are going to rotate one

```
servo_close(1);
delay(DELAY_SERVO);
```

Rotate

```
servo(0, 90);
delay(3*DELAY_MAGIC);
servo(0, 0);
```

Reset all of servos to their init angles for fixing servo occasional jitter

```
delay(DELAY_SERVO);
servo_init();
```

Check more source code and informations about servo and sensor on Raspberry: [MY GitHub](https://github.com/MouChiaHung/RaspberryPi)

Answer (score 0):

Try "sudo ./servo"
Hope it will work.